# Handle click outside of SmartGWT Window

Tags: java, gwt, mouseevent, smartgwt

I'm able to handle a click inside my window, but how can I trigger a function (`outsideClick()`) when the user clicks anywhere out of my `Window`?

My window is not modal, and it is possible for the user to select text in it (it act somewhat as a tooltip). However, I have to do some stuff when the user clicks out of the window, and I can't seem to work out how to do this.

I have already added a blurhandler on my form in the background, but of course, when the user tries to select some text in my opened window, the field blurs, and my `outsideClick()` function gets triggered as well (which should not happen).

EDIT - Also note that the popup `Window` contains a canvas with html content created as a string (please don't ask why, I know it's not very nice)

Anyone able to help me?

Comment: Can you filter in your click handler by getting the source?

Comment: Unfortunately the source of the event gives me the form on which I registered the clickHandler :( So no luck with that I'm afraid...

Comment: Did you register event for both the form and the window?

Comment: I solved it by getting pageRect of my Window, and then checking if the mouseclick happened within that rect.

Answer (score 2):

In Smartgwt, the class `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window` has a boolean propriety called `dismissOnOutsideClick`. If you set it at true, a click outside the bounds of the `Window` will have the same effect as pressing its cancel button.

Please note that this feature works only on modal windows.

```
Window w = new Window();
w.setWidth(100);
w.setHeight(100);
w.setShowModalMask(false);
//
w.setIsModal(true);    
w.setDismissOnOutsideClick(true);
//
w.addItem(new Label("Test"));
w.show();
```

Comment: There is no such function w.isModal(true) should be changed to w.setIsModal(true)